# Incorrect route resolved

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, routes

I have the following in my routes.rb

```
resources :webcasts do

   resource :slide_deck do
      get 'wizard', :on => :collection
      resources :slides
   end

end
```

[ Note that slide_deck is a singular resource ]

Running `$rake routes` gets me the following route related to slide_deck#wizard:

```
wizard_webcast_slide_deck GET    /webcasts/:webcast_id/slide_deck/wizard(.:format)          slide_decks#wizard
```

I can hit the url: `/webcasts/:webcast_id/slide_deck/wizard` without issues.

My problem is that the url helper; wizard_webcast_slide_deck, doesn't resolve to this url.

It resolves to: `/webcasts/:webcast_id/slide_decks/wizard` [ Note the plural of slide_decks ]

Obviously I can get round this by using a hardcoded url instead of the url helper, but what is causing this and how can I fix it?